# How to change the view of an InfoPath form only in edit mode?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I'm building a SharePoint app with a form utilizing multiple views for different stages. My form has the three standard views "display", "new" and "edit", which are automatically switched when entering the form by InfoPath (no rules yet).

Now I want to add a rule that switches the form to a different view depending on the value of a field. I know how to add such a rule in the load form rules. I added the condition "If field X is Y switch to view Z". Now whenever I open the form and the field X has a value of Y, the new view Z is shown.

My problem is that this rule triggers when the form is opened for viewing and editing. I want it to only trigger if the form is opened in edit mode. I do not want it to trigger if the form is in read only (display) mode.

So my question is: how to create a rule that will not trigger if the form is opened in read only mode?

Comment: Have you tried this:  In your rule condition, make the first check look at the value that you are using to switch views.      Condition: FormStatus is equal to Edit and SomeField is equal to X Action: ....

Comment: How can I check the FormStatus in a condition? This could solve my problem....

Comment: On my forms, I set a text field to my form status when it submits.  Text field: default value is New.  On my submit, I check the status of the text field, then change it as needed.  Something like this:  If FormStatus = New, Then set FormStatus = Submitted ...

Comment: This works to switch between new and edit views. I want to switch between different edit views, but KEEP a single, distinguished display view. Following your suggestion, the rule would trigger in display view as well and switch to the edit view.

Comment: I'm not following you on this sentence:  "I want to switch between different edit views, but KEEP a single, distinguished display view."  You want to switch between different Edit views, but keep another view active?  What are you using for a form solution?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. What I want is that the form load rules switch different views when the form is opened in edit mode. I want these rules not to trigger in display mode.

Comment: The same variable you are using to change views is what you should add to your Rules.  If your on open rule switches the view to Edit, then add that variable to your other rules.  You're making this too hard.

Comment: Perhaps we're talking about different things. I'm talking about form load rules in infopath. There is no such thing as an "on open rule". There's just one ruleset that is always triggered. Right now I added a single simple rule that says "If the field A is not empty then switch view to B".

Comment: When I said 'on open rule' I was referring to the Form Load.  Start from square one.... What variable drives your form to switch to different views?

Comment: I updated my question and added some details. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add a button on your form to switch to a different view. Once that button is clicked you can switch to the edit view and run your custom rule specific for that view.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your idea correctly. Adding a button to change the view might work. But is there such a thing as view-specific load rules? I experienced the load rules are form specific, not view specific. This causes the problem I have: the rules trigger even if the form is opened in the display view.

Comment: Load rules are specific to form not view. But you can set few condition on rules such that when form switches to a particular view you can run certain rules at that time.